# Как сделать widget в tray на подобии dr.web, google drive и так далее

Tags: python, pyqt5, qsystemtrayicon

Я написал приложение с помощью pyqt и хочу, чтобы оно открывалось в tray при нажатии левой кнопкой мыши на подобии dr.web, google drive:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть когда ты нажимаешь на иконку в tray, над ней открывается widget (без окна) в котором можно что-то делать.

Но я не знаю как это реализовать: в QMenu и QSystemTrayIcon нет методов для добавления widget'а, а при открытие widget'а отдельно в коде открывается доп окно, которого нет в dr.web и google drive. Надеюсь на помощь. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ThelArteml, пожалуйста, предоставьте код, который вы уже написали и лучше расскажите, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.